# Android two way data binding with room table models

Tags: android, android-room, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

So I have room model classes annotated with @Entity annotation which contain fields annotated with @ColumnInfo.

I also have a view that binds to the object of this model:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sadfadsdfasd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/assdsa"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@={fuelPrice.modification}" />
```

Like this it works when displaying EditText. It shows value from my model, but when I modify EditText, that modification is not being stored in my object even though I use @= signs which indicate two way binding.

So if I understand correctly, I can't really use POJO with simple primitive fields for two way data binding and instead I should have all fields as observables of required type or fields wrapped in LiveData?

If above case is true, does that mean that to have two way binding for room entities, I have to create separate class for each entity which would implement all the observable fields and update my entity object accordingly? Or is there a simplier solution?

**EDIT**
Above case was false. Seems like two way binding does work for simple POJO classes with appropriate getters and setters.

Comment: _modification is not being stored in my object_ do you really mean the object or you were expecting the modification to be saved into the db?

Comment: @Lelloman, I mean't my object, not database. I don't plan to use LiveData where all changes are directly stored in database, I just want to be able to modify the object via binding and only store it in db when needed.

Comment: Then I would expect that as well even if not using ObservableField, is `modification` a Kotlin `var`?

Comment: No, it's java String variable. It's displayed on EditText, but when changing it manually, setModification() method is not called.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your model? I just tested this and it is working as written in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>AFAIK</s> I just tested it, it should work without ObservableField given that `modification` is a private field with standard getters and setters. Using

`android:text="@={fueldPrice.modification}"`

and

```
class FuelPrice {
    private String modification;

    public String getModification() {
        return modification;
    }

    public String setModification(String modification) {
        this.modification = modification;
    }
}
```

It also works if you just use a public field

```
class FuelPrice {
    public String modification;
}
```

Comment: Must have been some other issue on my end, because now when I try it, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use observableField as following:

```
public class FuelPrice {
  public ObservableField<String> modification = new ObservableField<>();
  public TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcherAdapter() {
    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      if (!Objects.equals(modification.get(), s.toString())) {
        modification.set(s.toString());
      }
    }
  };
}
```

and update your XML as following:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/sadfadsdfasd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/assdsa"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:addTextChangedListener=”@{fuelPrice.watcher}” />
```

reference:

> [Two-way Android Data Binding](https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-data-binding-f9f9d3afc761)

.

Comment: So the problem with this approach is that I already have fuel price class which has fields like String, int and other types. So to have all of them in Observables I would actually have to create a separate model for use in binding and then transform it into Room's model, so I could save it to the database. If there's no other way around it, then I guess it's fine.