# Will I meet trouble if I use is as prefix of Booelan field in Room in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-room

`isStar` is a Booelan field in Room database, Code A works well, but Code B get the following  error.

*Details: Two-way binding cannot resolve a setter for boolean property 'isStar'*

Is there some trouble if I use is as prefix of Booelan  field in Room?

**Code A**

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chFavoriteContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@{aDetailViewModel.aMVoiceForEdit.isStar}"
    android:text="Favorite"
/>
```

**Code B**

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chFavoriteContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={aDetailViewModel.aMVoiceForEdit.isStar}"
    android:text="Favorite"
/>
```

**Both**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "voice_table", indices = [Index("createdDate")])
data class MVoice(
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0,
    var title:           String = "",
    var isStar:          Boolean = false,
    ...
): Parcelable {}
```

**Added Content**

It will work well if I replace `android:checked="@={aDetailViewModel.aMVoiceForEdit.isStar}"` with `android:checked="@{aDetailViewModel.aMVoiceForEdit.star}"`, you can see Code C.

And from the prompt of Android Studio (Image C), you will find the isStar is not displayed.

**Code C**

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chFavoriteContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@{aDetailViewModel.aMVoiceForEdit.star}"
    android:text="Favorite"
/>
```

**Image C**
[image]

Comment: Have a read on the docs there is more to 2 way binding then you have shown https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-custom-attrs

Answer (score 0):

Two-way data binding required live-data or observable type field
Hence to achieve this either

1)you need to convert that model class to an observable type class you can See below

```
class User : BaseObservable() {

@get:Bindable
var firstName: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName)
    }

@get:Bindable
var lastName: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName)
    }
}
```

2. You need to use bool live-data and need to observe for change. when it changes you have to update your model class manually

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: For C:  Android Studio automatically change getAB in databinding to AB , Similarly it changes naming method getISStar  to star property . so Your IsStar is nothing but star

Comment: And Please read about this also: https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-data-binding-f9f9d3afc761

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem using `isStar` as a Boolean field in Room database. Code A works because its a one way binding. For code B to work one should use an implementation of Observable, usually BaseObservable.

> The @={} notation, which importantly includes the "=" sign, receives data changes to the property and listen to user updates at the same time.
>
> In order to react to changes in the backing data, you can make your layout variable an implementation of Observable, usually BaseObservable

More [here](http://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way)

There is a similar question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078127/android-two-way-data-binding-with-room-table-models)

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Thanks for the update but ow its a becoming a bit confusing, in the code A & code B you showed that `isStar` is available but now in Image C you say that `isStar` is not availlable.

Comment: And `android:checked="@={aDetailViewModel.aMVoiceForEdit.star}"` would also be working fine.

Comment: I guess that you are trying to understand why you have to use `star` and why you cannot use `isStar`. In kotlin if the boolean variable start with `is` then its available via the name followed by `is` in your case its `star`. So if you change the variable name to `isIsStar` then it will be accessible by `isStar`. Hope this is what you were looking for.